# 2D Solid - Axisimmetric - Missing properties and material

Tags: structural-engineering, structural-analysis, buckling

Goodmorning,

I'm trying to understand how 2D solid elements work. I want to study the local buckling of a simple aluminium pipe with thin walls.
From what I understood, I can use 2D solid elements and model just a section of this pipe .

I've drawn a surface on the XZ plane (Z axis of simmetry). This surface is just a long but very thin rectangle that rapresents the pipe's wall. The pipe is open so no caps etc.
I applied the property 2d solid axisimmetric, my costrains and my loads. I then created my mesh with quadx elements.
In analysis, I selected SOL105 for bucking analysis.

When I run Nastran, I get some errors, the first one being:

```
USER FATAL MESSAGE 2011 (TA1)
NO PROPERTY ENTRY FOR ELEMENT TYPE QUADX
```

Indeed, checking the bdf file, there's no property to be found, nor the material definition!

I tried to group elements with no properties in Patran, but it found none.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

You almost certainly selected the wrong element type, and then didn't set up the special material data it needs. To quote from [this online Nastran manual](https://docs.plm.automation.siemens.com/data_services/resources/nxnastran/10/help/en_US/tdocExt/pdf/element.pdf)

> The CTRIAX and CQUADX elements ... are fully nonlinear elements supported in solution types
>   SOL 106 and 601 **but only support hyper-elastic material** defined on the
>   MATHP bulk data entry.

(My emphasis). Aluminium is not a hyperelastic material. For a linear buckling analysis, the element type you probably wanted was the CQUADX4.

Comment: in the nastran referece guide there's no CQUADX4, only CQUADX. When I create the mesh I do select quad4 elements for my axisimmetric elements and I get CQUADX. I'm using MSC Nastran 2018

Comment: Your error message said "QUADX", and the manual I referenced describes the difference between a QUADX and a QUADX4. Sorry, but I'm not a mind reader.

Comment: Yes but the manual you linked is for NX Nastran. Shouldn’t it be different from MSC Nastran?